# Drawing image instead of using labels on y axis of scatter graph in CorePlot

Tags: ios, iphone, core-plot

I want to use an image rather than labels on my x or y axis of scatter graph.

Please help how to do it

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom axis labels (via the `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone` labeling policy). Use a `CPTBorderedLayer` for the label content and set the `fill` to a `CPTFill` created using the desired image.